# Nativescript Webviewinterface Callback not working when you navigate back

Tags: nativescript

I am asking this question here because the github repo of the nativescript webviewinterface seems to be pretty inactive.

Basically I want to execute a JS function from Nativescript and get a result. This works fine with the webviewinterface plugin for the most part. When you navigate back however it does not work anymore. The JS function still gets executed but the nativescript callback will not execute anymore.

This seems like a fairly common use case to me. Here is an example repo: https://github.com/ll9/ns-webview-callback-bug (When you first hit 'call js' you will get a console.log but when you navigate back it woll not work anymore)
Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it specific to a platform? At least it worked for me with iOS - still logs `'js got called'` after navigating back from second page.

Comment: Hmm then it seems to be platform specific. I am using android and when I navigate back I do not get `js got called`anymore.

Comment: Just to be clear: When you navigate from the last page back to the webview `js got called` does not execute the callback anymore.